# Wordpress - PHP : How can I get the selected data in a form into a text area?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to collect the data inserted in a form (form with multiple choices - that is with radio buttons) and insert it in a text area.

The form was created with the "Extra Product Options" addon from wordpress, version 5.1
I use Elementor Pro (v3.4.2) to insert the shortcode into the text area.

I want to do this with a shortcode written into the functions.php file into my child theme.
The problem is : I have no idea how to do it and my searchs on google have returned without great results...

I only have found this little code from the support forum on wordpress but it's not really what I need as I don't have a cart to get the data from.

```
$products = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

foreach($products as $key => $product) 
{ // Iterate cart items
    if (array_key_exists(“thwepof_options”,$product))
    {
        $data = $product[“thwepof_options”];
        if(!empty($data))
        {
            foreach($data as $item)
            { // Iterate item options
                //var_dump($item);
                echo $item[‘label’];
                echo $item[‘value’];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me an idea on what type of code i'd need to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_shortcode('wporg', 'wporg_shortcode');
function wporg_shortcode( $atts = [], $content = null) {
    // add radio/checkbox buttons to the $content
    // add some extra javascript logic if needed?
    // 
    // always return
    return $content;
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/basic-shortcodes/

That's how you create custom shortcodes. Not sure if that was your issue though

Comment: My problem isn't really about how to create a shortcode. The thing is that I created a form with radio buttons using the plugin "Extra Product Options" and I want to collect, with a shortcode (implemented in a button), all the data inserted in it (that is: which radio buttons are selected).
But I don't know enough about PHP to write a shortcode to do this and there are no results when I search for solutions for this specific issue on the internet.

Comment: Then you have to add extra logic into the code I've wrote, that would pick all data from the database. You should call shortcode with parameter of the current post, so the code would know what are you searching there for